# Definition of normal linear functional

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

I am confused about the definition of normal linear functional.

In mamy reference books, when we define normal linear functionals , we require that the linear functional is positive. But in Kadison's book, the normal linear functional may not be positive.(See the theorem in the screenshot).

I don't understand why we need the positivity of linear functional when we defining the normality in many cases.

Comment: I suppose the emphasis on positive linear functionals is due to their far greater applicability.  This is like the emphasis on positive measures, as opposed to signed or complex valued measures.

Comment: My favorite definition of a normal linear functional on $M$  is
  $$
  \phi(a) = \langle a\xi,\eta\rangle , \quad\forall a\in  M,
  $$
  but it might require that you inflate  your Hilbert space to $H\otimes \ell^2$, where each  $a$ in $M$  is made to act  as
$a\otimes \text{id}$. In addition,  when $\varphi $ is positive, you may take $\xi =\eta $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kadison-Ringrose are very clear on this, in the section you are quoting. In previous sections, "normal" is only applied to states.

But in section 7.4, they state:

> 7.4.1. DEFINITION. If $\mathscr R$ is a von Neumann algebra acting on the Hilbert space $\mathscr H$, we denote by $\mathscr R_\#$ the linear space of linear functionals on $\mathscr R$ that are weak-operator continuous on the unit ball of $\mathscr R$ (the "normal" linear functionals on $\mathscr R$). We refer to $\mathscr R_\#$ are *predual* of $\mathscr R$.

And in the page right before the one you quoted:

> Applied to ultraweakly continuous states, Proposition 7.4.5 constitutes an additional condition to Theorem 7.1.12, The terms "normal" and "ultraweakly continuous" are now equally applicable to functionals on $\mathscr R$.

Comment: You mean that the normal linear functional must be positive in Kadison's book? But in the theroem of the the scrrenshot, it mentions that normal hermitian linear functional. If  a linear functional is positive , it must be hermitian.

Comment: No. What I mean, and what they say, is that in section 7.4 they use "normal" as an exact synonym of "ultraweakly continuous on bounded sets".

Comment: Thanks! So if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are tow normal states, then $\varphi-\psi$ is a normal hermitian linear functional.

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: @MartinArgerami do you mean “weak operator continuous on bounded sets”?

Comment: @SihOASHoihd: there's no difference. The ultraweak and the weak operator topologies agree on bounded sets.

Comment: @MartinArgerami True but wouldn’t it perhaps be better to say that "normal" is a synonym of "ultraweakly continuous on $R$“?

Comment: @SihOASHoihd: yes, you are right.